# JSON returned by TIdHTTP cannot be decoded

Tags: json, delphi, idhttp

I have the following code:

```
    var
      MemoryStream1: TMemoryStream;
      IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
      Bytes1: TBytes;
      s1: string;
    begin             
      IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      MemoryStream1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
      IdHTTP1.Get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', MemoryStream1);
      MemoryStream1.Position := 0;
      MemoryStream1.SaveToFile('C:\Temp\MemoryStream1.txt');
      MemoryStream1.Position := 0;
      SetLength(Bytes1, MemoryStream1.Size);
      MemoryStream1.Read(Bytes1[0], MemoryStream1.Size);
      s1 := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Bytes1);
```

It fails at the last line with the message "no mapping for the unicode character in the target multi-byte code page exists"

However, I can see the returned JSON clearly in HttpAnalyzer.

The file 'C:\Temp\MemoryStream1.txt' starts with the hex '1F8B0800000000000003DC9BED6F1BB7' when I am expecting something corresponding to { - a left brace - as the first character

when I try
    s1 := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(Bytes1);

String s1 contains "Chinese" characters.

Comment: Simply call `s1 := IdHTTP1.Get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all');`, overload that returns response to string and let Indy do the decoding work for you.

Comment: Thank you Victoria. That is certainly a simplification. However, I get the same characters in s1 and I need to find a way to turn it into a JSON string that I can process.

Comment: What happens when you call this in a web browser? Or a REST debug tool such as Postman? I'd bet the issue is with the server's response.

Comment: If you call it in a browser, it works fine. You get '[{"name":"Afghanistan","topLevelDomain":[".af"],' etc. I am sure I am making a trivial error, but I fail to find it.

Comment: Replacing https with http, I can not reproduce this. The resulting string (and the file on disk) are totally fine.

Comment: Great that you figured out your problem. But you shouldn't edit the answer into your question. You should be encouraged to post it as an actual answer below.

Comment: Sorry Jerry. I will try to fix that. :-)

Comment: @Alfred767: I'm with Günther on this. Using HTTP or HTTPS, I can't reproduce the issue.  Using the latest version of Indy 10 with Delphi XE2, the code shown in the question works properly as-is as expected, the JSON is saved and decoded correctly.

Comment: PS - Just as a side note, if you're going to download to a `TMemoryStream`, and then immediately save it to a file, then you should use `TFileStream` instead. This is especially important for very large files - surely you don't want to download it to memory, and then turn around and dump it into a file. Surely you'd want it to go directly to a file in the first place.

Comment: Thank you Jerry. The TMemoryStream was there solely to be able to look at the file. As Victoria pointed out, it was superfluous. It was only there for debugging purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I worked it out. Apparently, the gzip is not decompressed. One must do it oneself. Here goes:

```
    var
      IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
      a1: AnsiString;
      s1: string;
      MemoryStream1, MemoryStream2: TMemoryStream;
    begin             
      Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
      IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      MemoryStream1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
      MemoryStream2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
      IdHTTP1.Get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all', MemoryStream1);
      MemoryStream1.Position := 0;
      IdCompressorZLib1.DecompressGZipStream(MemoryStream1, MemoryStream2);
      FreeAndNil(MemoryStream1);
      MemoryStream2.Position := 0;
      SetLength(a1, MemoryStream2.Size);
      MemoryStream2.Read(a1[1], MemoryStream2.Size);   
     //  AnsiString a1 now contains the decompressed data
```

Comment: Your original code is not requesting compression from the server to begin with, so the server should not be sending a compressed response at all. If it does, that is a server-side bug that needs to be reported to the website admin. But even then, if the response is compressed, you don't need to decompress it manually. Assign a `TIdCompressorZLib` object to the `TIdHTTP.Compressor` property and let `TIdHTTP` handle the decompression for you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Using the latest version of Indy 10 with Delphi XE2, the response is not gzip compressed, and the original code shown in your question works fine as-is with no changes needed.

Comment: I have XE8. Maybe that is why it behaves differently

Comment: The Delphi version doesn't matter. Something else is going on. The server should not be compressing the response unless the client asks for it. So either your `TIdHTTP` is erroneously sending an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header when it shouldn't be (which it doesn't do by default without a `Compressor` assigned, unless you are setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding` property manually), or the code you have shown is not your real code.

Comment: I think you are correct Remy. Thank you for pointing this out.